# Angularjs json data name from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="day in days" >

    <td> {{ day }} </td>
    <td> 
        <p ng-repeat="item in itemId.Items"> is: {{ item.day  }}</p>
```

In the code, item is a json object having Mon, Tue, Wed, etc as names. These names are supplied from day variable.

When I used item.day, angular is checking for day name in item object which is not available. What is required is day should be replaced with the specific name like item.Mon

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
 <p ng-repeat="item in itemId.Items"> is: {{ item.day  }}
```

with

```
<p ng-repeat="item in itemId.Items"> is: {{ item[day]  }}
```

and your code should work.